# How to inject a virtual post (i.e. without adding it to the database)

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I use a WordPress blog and I want to show a post without adding anything to database.
What I want to say is:

I generate a post when page loads,and prepend it in homepage.
I've searched and found `wp_insert_post()` function but it also add to database.
How can i do this with php?

**For example:** 
There is a post array which is generated by a query.How can I insert my post to this array before page loaded?

I want clear my idea.Here's step by step what i want.

**1)**Im generating an array like that
$arr['title] = "my title",
$arr['content'] = "my content",

**2)**WP sends a query to database and have the posts am i right? And there is an array,to show on the theme and main page?
At this point i want to add my external array(generated in step1 ) to this array(generated by WP via a query)

**3)** By this way i will be able to add a post without adding it to my database.

Comment: Wut? This makes no sense - WP manages its posts in a database, so there is no way to create one without using it. Where does the stuff you want to premend come from? Wouldn't it be an option to just add it to the home page template?

Comment: I suspect the OP wants to inject a post via PHP rather than adding it to the database. i.e. a static post or randomly inserted advert?

Comment: @Pekka웃 my content will be generated when page loads.and i want to inject to posts array,and it will be shown on the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add your virtual post in one of your theme templates as raw HTML.

Alternatively, if you're feeling adventurous, you could modify the main query results and include your post inside:

```
add_action('loop_start', function($query){

  // create the post and fill up the fields
  $post = new WP_Post((object)array(
    'ID'           => -1,
    'post_title'   => 'Bla blah',
    'post_content' => 'Your content',
  ));

  // add it to the internal cache, so WP doesn't fire a database query for it
  // -1 is the ID of your post
  if(!wp_cache_get(-1, 'posts'))
    wp_cache_set(-1, $post, 'posts');

  // prepend it to the query
  array_unshift($query->posts, $post);
});
```

Comment: im not writing a theme,im writing a plugin.so my plugin should work with all the themes.Could this code warrant this?

Comment: It should work, though you may want to perform more checks, like `$query->is_main_query()` or `is_front_page()` etc. Is there any reason why you don't want to add this post to the database?

Comment: Yes there are several logical reasons.But i dont want to share.Thanks for your answer

Comment: i've done what you wrote above but it works for only one post.After that it doesnt work

Comment: i have 9 posts like that and i wanted to do this with a loop

Comment: Each needs to have a different ID. Use negative IDs to avoid clashes with real posts

Comment: function's parameter $query,what is this,where does it set

Answer (score 1):

[The currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14460668/4829915) causes the new post to delete the last post in the loop, because it doesn't update the post count. Here's my modified version that also includes:

1. Support for empty categories.
2. Only one place to declare the new post's ID.
3. Adding is_main_query() as the person who originally answered mentioned in a comment.
4. A setting to decide if the new post should be appended or prepended.
5. Hiding the post's date because otherwise you get something like 00000000. I could have used a dynamic date but it may be bad SEO to keep updating the date without updating the content.
6. Hiding the post's comment link because it just leads to the homepage.
7. A setting to control the post type. You might prefer **"page"** because **"post"** displays a general category, which I found no way to bypass. "Page" also looks more distinguished among other posts, assuming that's a good thing.

Here's the modified code:

```
function virtual_post($query) {
  $post_type = 'page'; // default is post
  if (get_class($query)=='WP')
     $query = $GLOBALS['wp_query'];
  if ($query->is_main_query()) {
     $append = true; // or prepend
     // create the post and fill up the fields
     $post = new WP_Post((object)array(
      'ID'           => -1,
      'post_title'   => 'Dummy post',
      'post_content' => 'This is a fake virtual post.',
      'post_date' => '',
      'comment_status' => 'closed'
     ));
     if ($post_type <> 'post')
       $post->post_type = $post_type;
     // add it to the internal cache, so WP doesn't fire a database query for it
     if(!wp_cache_get($post->ID, 'posts')) {
       wp_cache_set($post->ID, $post, 'posts');
       if ($query->post_count==0 || $append)
         $query->posts[] = $post;
       else
         array_unshift($query->posts, $post);
       $query->post_count++;
     }
  }
}

$virtual_post_settings = array('enable' => true, 'include_empty_categories' => true);
if ($virtual_post_settings['enable']) {
  if ($virtual_post_settings['include_empty_categories'])
    add_action('wp', 'virtual_post');
  else
    add_action('loop_start', 'virtual_post');
}
```